# RegEx for replacing punctuation excluding negative numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Currently, to remove punctuation from a string, I use:

```js
export function scrubPunctuation(text) {
  let reg = /\b[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+\B|\B[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+\b/g;
  return text.replace(reg, "");
}
```

but this also removes `-1`, where `-` is not so much "punctuation" as part of a numerical value.

How do I solve this problem?

Example use case:

I have take a string from a user that might look like this:

```js
const userStr = "  I want something, sort of, that has at least one property < -1.02 ?   "
```

Currently, my approach is to first `trim` the string to remove the leading / trailing white space.

Then I "scrub" punctuation from the string.

From the example of `userStr` above, I might eventually parse out (via some unrelated to regex):

```js
const relevant = ["something", "at least one", "<", "-1.02"]
```

In general, non-numeric punctuation is irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't it better to think about what you want to *leave* and focus on that, instead of what you want to *remove*?

Comment: Give us some examples of your input and your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the minus sign or the dot or comma removed form the digits, one option might be to capture what you want to keep (in this case a digit with an optional decimal part) and match what you want to remove.

```
(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuhMbu/1)

```js
let pattern = /(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+/g;
let str = "This is -4, -55 or -4,00.00 (test) 5,00";
let res = str.replace(pattern, "$1");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Split your first character set. Remove the hyphen from the first set and add a [Negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the hyphen:

`[-]+(?![0-9]) \\a Hyphen not followed by a number`

And the full expression:

`\b[-]+(?![0-9])|[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+\B|\B[.,()&$#![\]{}"']+\b`

Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/r8B1Cs/1)

Answer (score 1):

something like `/[,?!.']/g` could do the job and you add whatever you want

```js
const text = "bar........,foo,????!-1'poo!!!?'";

const res = text.replace(/[,?!.']/g, "")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would split it into two. 
First I would remove everything but alphanumeric and -.

```
/[^a-z0-9\-\s\n]/gi
```

It is a little more readable than your method and should give the same result unless there is some character you want to keep (like whitespace \s and newline \n).
To get rid of the punctuation "-", I would use:

```
/-(\d*)/g
```

So altogether:

```
export function scrubPunctuation(text) {
    let reg =  /[^a-z0-9\-\s\n]/gi;
    let reg2 = /-(\d*)/g;
    text = text.replace(reg, "");
    return text.replace(reg2, "$1");
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work